# For the same method, how does the JVM decide which nmethod to use

Tags: java, jvm, jit

As I know, JIT-compiled machine code is stored in nmethod. When osr happens, The whole method will also be compiled, not just the loop part. Hence, same method may have several nmethod(osr or method compilation).When the method is executed next time, according to what choice the nmethod?

I run a tomcat application and turn on the JVM flag -XX:+PrintTieredEvents. finding the method "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost" is always compiled and its run level is 0(Interpreter Execution), as if nmethod is not being used.

```
399.895003: [loop level=0 [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V] @190 queues=0,0 rate=0.946396 k=1.00,1.00 total=1684,79876 mdo=1538(0),77824(0) max levels=4,4 compilable=c1,c1-osr,c2,c2-osr status=idle]
399.895053: [compile level=4 [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V] @190 queues=0,0 rate=0.946396 k=1.00,1.00]

401.924422: [loop level=0 [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V] @190 queues=0,0 rate=1.021956 k=1.00,1.00 total=1684,81924 mdo=1538(0),79872(0) max levels=4,4 compilable=c1,c1-osr,c2,c2-osr status=idle]
401.924488: [compile level=4 [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V] @190 queues=0,0 rate=1.021956 k=1.00,1.00]

402.915345: [loop level=0 [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V] @190 queues=0,0 rate=0.996109 k=1.00,1.00 total=1684,82948 mdo=1538(0),80896(0) max levels=4,4 compilable=c1,c1-osr,c2,c2-osr status=idle]
402.915398: [compile level=4 [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V] @190 queues=0,0 rate=0.996109 k=1.00,1.00]
```

I dump the method's nmethods

```
address:0x00007f43cb17ce50 || size:2400 || methodName:NMethod for org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V || isOSR:true || lockedByVm:false || _entry_bci:190|| _state:0|| _exception_offset:1680|| _deoptimize_offset:1685|| _deoptimize_mh_offset:-1|| _orig_pc_offset:64|| _stub_offset:1680|| _consts_offset:368|| _oops_offset:1704|| _metadata_offset:1712|| _scopes_data_offset:1760|| _scopes_pcs_offset:2152|| _dependencies_offset:2344|| _handler_table_offset:2352|| _nul_chk_table_offset:2352|| _nmethod_end_offset:2400|| _stack_traversal_mark:0|| _compile_id:19658|| _comp_level:4|| _marked_for_deoptimization:0|| _entry_point:0x00007f43cb17cfc0|| _verified_entry_point:0x00007f43cb17cfc0|| _osr_entry_point:0x00007f43cb17cfd0

address:0x00007f43cb1813d0 || size:10152 || methodName:NMethod for org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V || isOSR:false || lockedByVm:false || _entry_bci:-1|| _state:0|| _exception_offset:6235|| _deoptimize_offset:6240|| _deoptimize_mh_offset:-1|| _orig_pc_offset:64|| _stub_offset:6160|| _consts_offset:592|| _oops_offset:6256|| _metadata_offset:6296|| _scopes_data_offset:6520|| _scopes_pcs_offset:9040|| _dependencies_offset:9808|| _handler_table_offset:9848|| _nul_chk_table_offset:10040|| _nmethod_end_offset:10152|| _stack_traversal_mark:0|| _compile_id:25500|| _comp_level:4|| _marked_for_deoptimization:0|| _entry_point:0x00007f43cb181620|| _verified_entry_point:0x00007f43cb181640||_osr_entry_point:0x00007f43cb181620

address:0x00007f43cd81fc50 || size:20000 || methodName:NMethod for org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V || isOSR:true || lockedByVm:false || _entry_bci:105|| _state:0|| _exception_offset:13508|| _deoptimize_offset:13632|| _deoptimize_mh_offset:-1|| _orig_pc_offset:328|| _stub_offset:13168|| _consts_offset:1104|| _oops_offset:13656|| _metadata_offset:13704|| _scopes_data_offset:13888|| _scopes_pcs_offset:17584|| _dependencies_offset:19168|| _handler_table_offset:19192|| _nul_chk_table_offset:19720|| _nmethod_end_offset:20000|| _stack_traversal_mark:0|| _compile_id:25194|| _comp_level:3|| _marked_for_deoptimization:0|| _entry_point:0x00007f43cd8200a0|| _verified_entry_point:0x00007f43cd8200c0|| _osr_entry_point:0x00007f43cd82287b
```

Answer (score 3):

Every nmethod has [`_entry_bci`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/c414c554b38b/src/hotspot/share/code/nmethod.hpp#l73) - the bytecode index at which this nmethod can start execution. Non-OSR compilations have `_entry_bci == InvocationEntryBci (-1)`.

Methods compiled for on-stack replacement (OSR) are never reused for a regular method entry.

In fact, a Java method may have at most one actual [compiled entry point](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/c414c554b38b/src/hotspot/share/oops/method.hpp#l108) (not counting OSR and AOT entries). If a method is re-compiled at a higher tier, the entry is replaced to point to the new code, and previous nmethods are marked as `not_entrant`, though currently active frames may continue running the old version.